# MKMapView visibleMapRect not completely visible

Tags: ios8, mkmapview, mapkit, overlay, region

I have a `MKMapView` that marks a specific region using `MKPolygon`. I want the map to have minimum zoom factor that fits inside the mapView / screen, means completely visible.

To achieve this I tried the following

```
MKPolygon *overlay;
[[self mapView] setVisibleMapRect:[overlay boundingMapRect] edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(16, 16, 16, 16) animated:YES];
```

Unfortunately my mapView does not set the whole rect visible. The rect **fills** the map instead of **fitting**.

This is what I need vs. what I got:

[image: what i want] vs. [image]

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: That can't be the actual code (overlay is not declared as a pointer, it's not initialized, boundingRect should be boundingMapRect, etc).  In the real code, are you sure the overlay is pointing to the right one?  Is there another setRegion or setVisibleMapRect call happening after this?  Is the MKMapView frame set to the screen or does it go beyond the screen?  Looks like the map height is correct but the width might be too wide.

Comment: @Anna: This is the one and only overlay on the mapView and there is just one `-setVisibleMapRect:` call. I wrote just a few lines in the `-viewDidLoad` method to see how it works. I corrected the typo with `boundingMapRect` and the missing pointer

Comment: Thanks, @Anna, you gave me the right idea, see my answer below. I don't have many experiences with `MKMapView` yet, so I didn't see it =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the answer. It didn't have to do anything with the `MKMapView`. I just started using size classes in Xcode 6 and so there was my problem located.

The call to `[MKMapView -setVisibleMapRect:edgePanning:animated:]` was made too early, namely in the `-viewDidLoad` method.

When I was thinking of [Annas comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541162/mkmapview-visiblemaprect-not-completely-visible/26554344#comment41716208_26541162) and probed a bit I discovered the she was totally right. Then it dawned on me that I should call the mapView method later, e.g. `-viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

As I moved the one line it worked just perfectly! Thanks, [Anna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467105/anna)!

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass `[overlay boundingMapRect]` through `-[[self mapView] mapRectThatFits:]`.

> A map rectangle that is still centered on the same point of the map but whose width and height are adjusted to fit in the map view’s frame.

Comment: This does not change anything... :/ But I found a solution now.

Answer (score 0):

If -setVisibleMapRect is set in -viewDidLayoutSubviews, then the visible maprect will be reset when the map is zoomed in/out.

My enhancement is: define a class level flag and invoke -setVisibleMapRect only if that flag is on. Once -setVisibleMapRect is invoked, turn the flag off. From now on, zooming in/out the map won't reset the visible maprect. Here is my code in Swift:

```
var resetMapRect = true // class level variable

override void viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    if resetMapRect {
        // set visible maprect here
        resetMapRect = false // no more setting maprect
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but as you can see we did already find the right answer and it was a different issue :-) but so we also have a Swift solution...